# Spacing on inside of image in grid

Tags: css, layout, css-float, grid-layout

I apologize, I'm sure the solution to this must be on this site somewhere, but I'm not sure what words to search for to find it.

I'm trying to create a grid of images (2 wide x unlimited down) using a left float with space between the left and right image on the page. I'm familiar with the first child command, and I've tried using it here, but this only works on removing the left margin on the first image, and not all images on the left side.

How do I go about lining up an unlimited (the list will end, it's just different for every page) amount of images with no space on the outer edges, but space in the inside?

My CSS:

```
section{
width: 940px;   
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;    
}

.package{
width: 450px;
height: 180px;
background-color: #f1f6fb;
float: left;
margin: 20px 0 20px 40px;
}

.package-image{
margin: 20px;
float: left;
}

.package-description{
width: 255px;
height: 160px;
float: left;
margin-top: -10px;
}

.favourite{
position:relative;
top: 30px;
left: -150px;
}

.first {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

My html:

```
<section>
<div class="package first">
<img class="package-image" src="./images/aeyracakes_sakuraminicakes-_1_medium.jpg">
<img class="favourite" src="./images/favourite-no.png">
<div class="package-description">
<h4>package name</h4>
<h5><a href="#">company name</a></h5>
<p>package description</p>  
</div>  
</div>

<div class="package">
<img class="package-image" src="./images/aeyracakes_sakuraminicakes-_1_medium.jpg">
<img class="favourite" src="./images/favourite-no.png">
<div class="package-description">
<h4>package name</h4>
<h5><a href="#">company name</a></h5>
<p>package description</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="package">
<img class="package-image" src="./images/aeyracakes_sakuraminicakes-_1_medium.jpg">
<img class="favourite" src="./images/favourite-no.png">
<div class="package-description">
<h4>package name</h4>
<h5><a href="#">company name</a></h5>
<p>package description</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the images to display next to each other, or do you want rows of two "package" divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :nth-child(even|odd) on your packages to select your left or right image.

```
.package:nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 0;
}
.package:nth-child(even){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```